# Loading images from different folders

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, directory

So I want to load different images from different folders. I have a little puzzle where you can change the format for example to 3x3, 3x4, 4x3 and 4x4 etc. and now I want that when someone clicks on "select format" and choose 3x3 it loads images from the 3x3 folder and if someone clicks on 4x4 I want images from the 4x4 folder.

The folder looks like /images/3x3/1.png or /images/4x4/1.png. As it is right now all pictures are loading from the same folder. Any ideas how to fix that? I tried it making a new variable and then using if statement to chose from different folders but it didnt work.

Here is the code for a better understanding:

code:
    http://jsfiddle.net/Cuttingtheaces/vkyxgwo6/19/

the part where the folders should be changed because right now it only uses the images folder to get the images:

```
function changeFormat(x, y) {
    var puzzlepieces = [];
    var finalValue = x * y - 2;

for (var i = 0; i <= finalValue; ++i) {
    puzzlepieces.push(i);
}

puzzlepieces.push('blank')
createSlidingpuzzle(puzzlepieces, x, y);
}

function createSlidingpuzzle(puzzlepieces, x, y) {

var puzzle = '<div id="slidingpuzzleContainer' + x + 'x' + y + '">';
cols=x;
puzzlepieces=shuffle(puzzlepieces);
for (var puzzleNr = 0; puzzleNr < puzzlepieces.length; ++puzzleNr) {
    puzzle += '<img src="images/' + puzzlepieces[puzzleNr] + '.png" class="puzzlepiece" id="position' + puzzlepieces[puzzleNr] + '" alt="' + puzzlepieces[puzzleNr] + '" onclick="shiftPuzzlepieces(this);" width="100" height="100" />';
}
puzzle += '</div>';

showSlidingpuzzle(puzzle);
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have url for image in format like: "/images/3x3/1.png" than you have to change this line of code:

```
puzzle += '<img src="images/' + puzzlepieces[puzzleNr] + '.png" class="puzzlepiece" id="position' + puzzlepieces[puzzleNr] + '" alt="' + puzzlepieces[puzzleNr] + '" onclick="shiftPuzzlepieces(this);" width="100" height="100" />';
```

to

```
puzzle += '<img src="images/' + x + 'x' + y + '/' +[puzzleNr] + '.jpg" class="puzzlepiece" id="position' + puzzlepieces[puzzleNr] + '" alt="' + puzzlepieces[puzzleNr] + '" onclick="shiftPuzzlepieces(this);" width="100" height="100" />';
```

here is a working example forked of your version: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/an423xyc/). If you inspect the img elment you can see that it has source like this

```
src="images/3x3/4.jpg"
```

Comment: how can I inspect it to see the source?

Comment: it works that it loads the pictures from different folders but it looks like my function shiftPuzzlepieces(el) and "function shuffle(array)" doesnt work anymore. why is that?

Comment: nvm i figured it out myself thanks alot for your answer